# Using "CASE WHEN" and "IN" condition in MapBox GL JS?

Tags: geojson, style, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to set data driven style for a layer in MapBox GL JS. I want to use two fields: "category" (string) and "status" (string) and display the points with custom SVG icons. I am trying to write a filter that will match on values from these two properties of the data source.

I'm just want to find the correct syntax for this:

```
CASE WHEN category IN ('1,'2','3') AND status = 'OK' THEN icon = 'svg2'
WHEN category IN ('4',5') AND status = 'OK' THEN icon = 'svg1'
ELSE icon = 'svg3'
```

So, I have to convert this expression to MapBox syntax.

I wrote this expression:

```
[
  "match",
  ["get", "category"],
  ["1", "2", "3"],
  "svg1",
  ["4", "5"],
  "svg2",
  "svg3"
]
```

But this is not enough. I want to use two conditions with AND operator, because I must check the "status" property too.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Mapbox GL expressions `case` at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#case and `all` at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#all.

Your expression could then looks something like:

```
[ "case",
    ["all"
      ["match", ["get", "category"], ["1", "2", "3"]],
      ["==", ["get", "status"], "OK"]
    ], "svg1",
    ["all"
      ["match", ["get", "category"], ["4", "5"]],
      ["==", ["get", "status"], "OK"]
    ], "svg2",
    "svg3"
]
```